# What the correct way to realize ListView in ReactNative for realm db query?

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, realm

I am going to use RealmDB instead AsyncStorage in my application. It is more conveniently for me. But i have a problem with render results in ListView component. There are two ways to get data in my app: 
- fetch from api url:

```
return fetch('myurl')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
                    this.setState({

                        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
```

- get data from realmdb for offline mode.

RealmDB works perfect. It is easy to write and get data from queries. I can check it in console, but I can't render it in my ListView component. Render fetch results works as usual.

```
    componentDidMount() {     
            let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
            let query=realm.objects('QueryObjects');
            this.setState({
                dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(query)
            })

        }
render() {

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>

            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) =>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <View
                            style={{flex:2}} >
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onLearnMore(rowData)}>
                            <Text
                            >{rowData.title}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex:1, paddingLeft: 5}} >
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onLearnMore(rowData)}>
                            <Text>{rowData.price}</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

This doesn't work. But, if I try to call map function for realm query, I can see correct data for every query element in console.

Comment: Is https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#react-native-listview useful?